# Regex to allow only number(integer no decimal points) between -130 to 30

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

Already done regex for **0** to **50**

`^(?:[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|50)$`

its working fine. Now trying to write with negative numbers like regex only allow **-130** to **30** without decimal points.

Comment: Why not just convert the string to a number and then see if it's between -130 and 30?

Comment: Actually I have to apply on HTML input text field maybe the user can enter the ex.testtest couldn't convert. That's why I need a regex. My client also wants regex only(most of the validations are done in regex that's why).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(\-[1-9][0-9]?|\-1(0[0-9]|[12][0-9]|30)|[0-9]|[12][0-9]|30)$
```

- `\-[1-9][0-9]?` checks for -99 to -1
- `\-1(0[0-9]|[12][0-9]|30)` checks for -130 to -100
- `[0-9]|[12][0-9]|30` checks for 0 to 30